# How to sum against id in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
id leavetype leavecount
=======================
1  Medical   2
1  Annual    3
1  Casual    2
1  Lwop      1
```

I want to sum against `id` like `leavecount` sum is 8 against `id`:

```
id  grand total
================
1      8
```

and I am using this code:

```
foreach($dbh->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt
                     FROM ams 
                     where empid= $empid 
                     GROUP BY empid 
                     HAVING leavecount = ''") as $grandtotal) 
{  
    echo "<table ><tr ><td style='border: 0px; ' >" . $grandtotal['cnt'] . "</td></tr></table>";    
}
?>
```

Comment: I think this will help you: `SELECT id, sum(leavecount) as grand_total FROM ams GROUP BY id`

Comment: have you tried "select id, SUM(leavecount) group by id" ?

Comment: Why exactly have you added `HAVING leavecount = ''`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$dbh->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt
                FROM ams 
                where empid= $empid 
                GROUP BY empid");
$dbh->execute();
$row = $dbh->fetchAll();
```

`$row` will then contain the count.

(It is really bad practice to put variables directly into a query, you can insert them by putting `:empid` in the query, then add an associative array in the execute with `:empid => $empid`)

(Regarding `leavecount`, did you want to select the count where they have no leavecount? If so, you want to use `WHERE` not `HAVING`)

Comment: its not giving me the result

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of `HAVING leavecount = ''` It forces your query to filter out the result-set having leavecount to blank string `''`.

Also if you already have `empid` to filter the result by employee id there is no need to `GROUP BY` the result. Use `GROUP BY` only when you want to Group the result where three there could be more then one employee ID.

You also need to replace `count()` function with `sum()` to sum the values of `leaves` column, what you're doing right now is counting the rows instead you need to sum the values of leaves column.

So Your query will look something like this when you have `empid` with you.

```
SELECT SUM(leavecount) as cnt
                FROM ams 
                where empid = $empid
```

In case you want to get the leaves count of all the employees, **GROUP BY** the result-set by `empid`.

```
SELECT empid,SUM(leavecount) as cnt
                FROM ams 
                GROUP BY empid
```

Answer (score 0):

sum in PHP is possible.

create an array with $ID as array id and $Value as array value and a function to update the value based on id.

```
$idSum = array();

function addSum ($idSum as array(), $id, $value){
  $idSum[$id] = $idSum[$id] + $value;
}
```

call addSum function in foreach.

Comment: It would be much more effecient to use inbuilt count functions in sql but this certainly is a way. :)

Comment: I agree... I just try to provide the direct answer to the question, in case there is some reason to do sum in php...